# Placing/changing cursor position to a new line after the table

Tags: vba, ms-word, export-to-word, word-table

The following code picks and places Excel data to the table in a Word file.

```vb
Sub test_table()
    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc
    Dim objSelection
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
    
    objWord.Visible = True
    objWord.Activate
    
    objSelection.Font.Size = 12
    objSelection.Font.Name = "Arial"
    objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    objSelection.TypeText "Accordingly, the " & vbLf
    
    Set country_table = objDoc.Tables.Add(objSelection.Range, 4, 5)
    
    With country_table
        
        With .Borders
            .enable = True
            .outsidecolor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .insidecolor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
       
        .Rows(1).shading.backgroundpatterncolor = RGB(230, 230, 230)
        .cell(1, 1).Range.InsertAfter "Part Number"
        .cell(1, 2).Range.InsertAfter "Item Description"
        .cell(1, 3).Range.InsertAfter "% of change in MRP"
        .cell(1, 4).Range.InsertAfter "% of change in offered rate"
        .cell(1, 5).Range.InsertAfter "Discount"
        For i = 1 To 3
            'For j = 1 To 3
                .cell(i + 1, 1).Range.InsertAfter ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview").Cells(12 + i, 1).Text
                .cell(i + 1, 2).Range.InsertAfter ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview").Cells(12 + i, 2).Text & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview").Cells(12 + i, 4).Text
                If IsError(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(16, (5 * i) - 2).Value) Then
                    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(16, (5 * i) - 2).Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then
                        .cell(i + 1, 3).Range.InsertAfter "NA"
                    End If
                Else
                    .cell(i + 1, 3).Range.InsertAfter ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(16, (5 * i) - 2).Text
                    
                End If
                
                '.cell(i + 1, 3).Range.InsertAfter ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(16, (5 * i) - 2).Text
                If IsError(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(17, (5 * i) - 2).Value) Then
                    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(17, (5 * i) - 2).Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then
                        .cell(i + 1, 4).Range.InsertAfter "NA"
                    End If
                Else
                    .cell(i + 1, 4).Range.InsertAfter ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(17, (5 * i) - 2).Text
                    
                End If
                '.cell(i + 1, 4).Range.InsertAfter ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(17, (5 * i) - 2).Text
                .cell(i + 1, 5).Range.InsertAfter ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(18, (5 * i) - 2).Text
            'Next j
        Next i
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

At the end of the execution of the subroutine, the cursor is landed the beginning of cell `(1,1)`. Whereas, I wanted to place the cursor just after the table in a new line.

Comment: Cursor or insertion position? I've skimmed these three answers and all of them are insertion position, not cursor. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InsertAfter method` does NOT reposition the cursor in Word. To additionally move the cursor, you can use other approaches such as:

> Option 1

```vb
    country_table.Select
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=5, Count:=1
```

> Option 2

```vb
    objDoc.Content.MoveStart Unit:=1, Count:=country_table.Range.End
    objDoc.Content.Collapse Direction:=1
    objDoc.Content.Select
```

The provided code snippet should be integrated right before `End Sub`.

Comment: option 1 returns the run-time error at line 2:"Object doesn't support this property or method". But, after execution of first line, the whole table is getting selected.

Comment: @JOSHYTR When running this Word code from Excel VBA, the Word constants need to be changed to their corresponding values. Please try the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to place the cursor in the first paragraph after the table:

```
country_table.Range.Next(4, 1).Select 'wdParagraph = 4
objWord.Selection.Collapse 1  'wdCollapseStart
```

`Range.Next` identifies the next range based on the starting point (range of your table) and the unit (`wdParagraph`).

Comment: The cursor stays at cell(1,1) of the word table yet.

Comment: Where did you place the code snippet?

Comment: After "End With"

Comment: Ahh - this code is written in Excel - therefore you have to put `objWord` before `Selection`. I updated my answer.

Comment: It throws runtime error '438'. Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Sorry - now the code works, had to replace the Word-constants to their numeric values

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing that is to add `objDoc.Characters.Last.Select` after the `End With`.

However, it would be far better to avoid using `Selection` altogether. It is also poor practice to use Late Binding (declaring Word as an untyped object) as this practice has no advantages when working across the Office suite. Instead you should set a reference to the Word library.

```
Sub test_table()
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    
    objWord.Visible = True
    objWord.Activate
    
    With objDoc.Content
        With .Font
            .Size = 12
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
        .Text "Accordingly, the " & vbCr
    
        Set country_table = .Tables.Add(.Characters.Last, 4, 5)
    End With
    
    With country_table
        
        With .Borders
            .enable = True
            .outsidecolor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .insidecolor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
       
        .Rows(1).shading.backgroundpatterncolor = RGB(230, 230, 230)
        .cell(1, 1).Range.InsertAfter "Part Number"
        .cell(1, 2).Range.InsertAfter "Item Description"
        .cell(1, 3).Range.InsertAfter "% of change in MRP"
        .cell(1, 4).Range.InsertAfter "% of change in offered rate"
        .cell(1, 5).Range.InsertAfter "Discount"
        For i = 1 To 3
            'For j = 1 To 3
            .cell(i + 1, 1).Range.InsertAfter ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview").Cells(12 + i, 1).Text
            .cell(i + 1, 2).Range.InsertAfter ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview").Cells(12 + i, 2).Text & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview").Cells(12 + i, 4).Text
            If IsError(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(16, (5 * i) - 2).Value) Then
                If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(16, (5 * i) - 2).Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then
                    .cell(i + 1, 3).Range.InsertAfter "NA"
                End If
            Else
                .cell(i + 1, 3).Range.InsertAfter ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(16, (5 * i) - 2).Text
                    
            End If
                
            '.cell(i + 1, 3).Range.InsertAfter ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(16, (5 * i) - 2).Text
            If IsError(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(17, (5 * i) - 2).Value) Then
                If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(17, (5 * i) - 2).Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then
                    .cell(i + 1, 4).Range.InsertAfter "NA"
                End If
            Else
                .cell(i + 1, 4).Range.InsertAfter ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(17, (5 * i) - 2).Text
                    
            End If
            '.cell(i + 1, 4).Range.InsertAfter ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(17, (5 * i) - 2).Text
            .cell(i + 1, 5).Range.InsertAfter ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Negotiation").Cells(18, (5 * i) - 2).Text
            'Next j
        Next i
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```